# PHP menu with .active classes

Tags: php, navigation

I'm trying to build a navigation in php and add an `.active` class to the `<li>` element if the page displays. I found this code and it works for the top level elements, i.e. it will apply the `.active` class to the `<li>` when the selected page loads.

```
<?php
$nav = <<<NAV
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/section1/">Section 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/section2/">Section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
NAV;

$lines = explode("\n", $nav);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $current = false;
    preg_match('/href="([^"]+)"/', $line, $url);
    if (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0, 5) == substr(@$url[1], 0, 5)) {
        $line = str_replace('<a h', '<a  class="active" h', $line);
    }
    echo $line."\n";
}
?>
```

However, when I add some child pages to the html these child pages also inherit the `.active` class even when the parent page is displayed. Likewise, if a child page is displayed the parent also inherits the `.active` class.

```
<?php
$nav = <<<NAV
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/section1/">Section 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/section1/child-page-1">Child Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/section1/child-page-2">Child Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/section2/">Section 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
NAV;

$lines = explode("\n", $nav);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $current = false;
    preg_match('/href="([^"]+)"/', $line, $url);
    if (substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], 0, 5) == substr(@$url[1], 0, 5)) {
        $line = str_replace('<a h', '<a  class="active" h', $line);
    }
    echo $line."\n";
}
?>
```

Is there a way to adapt the php so only the `<li>` to the corresponding page inherits the `.active` class. Also if the `.active` element was a child then the parent `<li>` would get a class name like `.active-trail`?

Alternatively is there a better way to do this via another language like jQuery?

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I would rather build your nav from an array or object. Then you don't have to search and replace aftwerwards.

Comment: And what has this to do with JSON or JQuery

Comment: Sorry, the header was from another post I was going to submit a while back but resolved. The system remembered this and I forgot to update the subject for this post.